Узнать установлено ли PWA на устройстве с другого сайта
Есть приложение PWA на поддомене pwa.example.ru и есть сайт на домене example.ru
Хочу попробовать сделать popup который отображался только тем пользователям которые зашли на сайт example.ru и у которых не установлено PWA, для этого нужно сделать проверку на сайте example.ru
Каким образом это сделать и возможно ли это вообще?

А как же getInstalledRelatedApps() который проверяет установлено ли приложение на устройстве пользователя

Мне кажется в вашей "хотелке" упущен главный момент: у вас нет никакой возможности узнать установлено ли у пользователя PWA и неважно с какого вашего домена или поддомена. Но... есть возможность а) узнать работает ли сейчас пользователь через PWA; б) узнать запускалось ли PWA-приложение и при помощи cookie зафиксировать этот момент, а потом воспользоваться. Но и тут, с кукисами, не всё гладко, уж лучше сразу передавать инфу через переменную в профиле.

LureRed, если вы мне, извините хотел дописать свой коммент, но поздно было править, вот и вывернулся. getInstalledRelatedApps() всё ещё в эксперементальной стадии и не для всех браузеров. Причём не совсем понятно будет ли он слушать домен и поддомен одновременно.

тогда вопрос снят на неопределенное время)))
